# Is it possible to check the expected colorcode in E2E testing using Testcafe?

Tags: node.js, user-interface, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

> Is it possible to check the expected colorcode in E2E testing using Testcafe?
>   Am using Testcafe tool for E2E testing, I wanna check the color is green for the text, How can I check it.. Is it possible to do these type of UI test in E2E test??

Comment: Please add your code that illustrates how you set the element color so that I can check for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use TestCafe to test your color code. For instance, if your color is defined using the CSS style property, you can check it as follows:

```
test('check the green color', async t => {

    const elementStyle = await Selector('#targetElement').style;

    await t.expect(elementStyle.color)
           .eql("rgb(0, 128, 0)", "the color must be green!");

});
```

See also: [DOM Node State](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html)